django permission using UserPassesTestMixin
I tried to use the user.has_perm() method, but it always returns False.
def test_func(self):
        # Define your custom access control logic here
        user = self.request.user
        return user.is_authenticated and user.has_perm('CreateGroup.add_group')


What is the name of the app? can you share the model?
